# Linear Interpolation to find coord in triangle

Tags: c++, geometry, sdl, interpolation, linear-interpolation

Suppose you have the following three points `A`, `B`, and `C` as shown in the following picture:

[image]

The points are always sorted according to their vertical offset, so the top most point is always A. Sometimes B and C could have the same y coordinate.

I'm trying to find the x coordinate for point D. I can find the Y coordinate for D by interpolating points `A.y` and `C.y` at `(B.y / (C.y - A.y))`. I'm doing my interpolation using the following formula (in C++)

```
float linearInterpolation(float a, float b, float t)
{
    return a + (t * (b - a));
}
```

So in other words, `D.y = linearInterpolation(A.y, C.y, (B.y - A.y) / (C.y - A.y))`

So to summarize, my question is: how do I find `D.x`?

Thanks

--

Answer:

Just to clarify, here's the solution that was suggested and worked:

```
D.x = A.x + (B.y - A.y) * (C.x - A.x) / (C.y - A.y);
D.y = B.y;
```

As illustrated in the image below:

[image]

Comment: You have this backwards.  The y coordinate of D equals the y coordinate of B (substitute your formula into linearInterpolation and you will find everything cancels, leaving B.y).  You need the linear interpolation only for x...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It it is the *x* coordinate that requires interpolation. The *y* coordinates of *B* and *D* are equal on your diagram.

```
D.x = A.x + (B.y - A.y) * (C.x - A.x) / (C.y - A.y);
D.y = B.y;
```

You should also make a provision for the case of C.y == A.y, where D.x could be anywhere between A.x and C.x. One way to do this is to not draw triangles, for which `abs(C.y - A.y) < delta`, with the `delta` being on the order of magnitude of 1 pixel.

Comment: Fairly sure the first line should be `A.x + (A.y - D.y) * (A.x - C.x)/(A.y - C.y).`

Comment: @EthanSteinberg, if the slope is positive and D.y is greater than A.y, then D.x must be greater than A.x. So, the first term should be (B.y - A.y). Switching the signs on the slope calculation (or on any pair of terms) makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

```
D.y = B.y

delta_x = C.x - A.x 
delta_y = C.y - A.y 

dist_y = B.y - A.y

percent = dist_y / delta_y

D.x = A.x + percent * delta_x
```

Answer (score 1):

The function for the line AC is `y = mx + b`.

**m = (A.y - C.y)/(A.x - C.x)**

You can then substitute A in: `A.y = A.x * m + b`

**b = A.y - A.x *m**

You need to calculate x from y, so swap the function around.

mx = y -b

**x = (y -b)/m**

Those are three steps to find the x from the y along that side of a triangle.
Note that you don't need to do any interpolation to find Dy. Simply, D.y = B.y.

Note that you can probably optimize what I have just written into a smaller series of steps. I think its better to write easier to read code though.

Comment: You could think of it in terms of the line function or you could think of it in terms of unit cancellation. Then you immediately know that the *x* offset is the product of another *x* offset and a ratio of two *y* offsets. :)